# Generate trees based on number of nodes and children allowed

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, loops, tikz-trees

I am doing an experiment, and would like to generate images of [Binary Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and [Exponential Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_tree) using LaTeX.

The difference between these two structures is the number of children allowed per node at each level. Binary Trees have a maximum of two, whereas Exponential Trees have 2<sup>dimension</sup> (with root being dimension = 1).

How would I be able to generate these trees using loops, so I could use a slightly modified Binary Tree TeX to generate the Exponential Tree?

Comment: You have a few options such as the `tree` library of TikZ, or [Tikz-qtree](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-qtree) but the question is not clear. Without your code it's not likely to get an answer to your question as it is.

Comment: A binary tree with 32 nodes will be 6 dimensions long (1 node away from 5 dimensions). An exponential tree with 32 nodes will be 4 dimensions long. Here is a list showing differences: `d1:{1,1}, d2:{2,2}, d3:{4,8}, d4:{8,64}`

Comment: So you want to just give the dimension number and get the tree automatically? An example would really clarify your goal with a Minimum Working Example.

Comment: There was a question about automatically generating binary trees a while back: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6258/86 Do any of the answers there look useful?