# How to draw this 3D H-layout recursive tree with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-trees, 3d, recursion

**Background:**

This is an extension problem from my last post [How to draw the recursive H-Layout tree using Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145116/how-to-draw-the-recursive-h-layout-tree-using-tikz). The (2D) H-layout tree is actually from the VLSI layout problem in computer science. I have received excellent solutions to the last post. Now, I am further interested in its 3D extension.

> 3D H-Layout tree: It is a recursive structure whose basic units are transformed 3D 
>   H-layout. The 3D H-layout consists of three mutually perpendicular *mata-edges*. Each *meta-edge* is composed by three nodes connected by two edges.

The following image shows a basic 3D H-layout unit:
[image: The basic 3D H-layout unit]

A simple 3D H-layout tree is as follows (**Note:** in this image, just the red part grows recursively. I would prefer the solution in which both the blue part and the red part grow simultaneously):
[image: A simple 3D H-layout tree]

**Problem:**

> How to draw this 3D H-layout recursive tree using Tikz? The visualization will be beneficial for my further investigation of such structure.

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @PaulGessler I would like to provide an MWE. However, I totally have no idea how to draw such images with Tikz. Sorry for that.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. Even a basic first try is better than nothing. Have you tried to draw the tree in 2d first? That might be a good starting point for the learning experience if nothing else.

Comment: @PaulGessler This is actually an extension of my other problem, which is concerned about [the 2d case](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145116/23098). I now want to study the 3d geometrically. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with recursion in Tikz.