# How to draw up a hierarchical tree diagram for taxonomic classification

Tags: diagrams, trees

Please show me the most simple, elegant code for this:

[image]

How to do it in other words.

Comment: You could have a look at TikZ and its possibilities to draw trees: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/ (I admit I never used them myself yet, so I can not quickly create an example)

Comment: ...or use the `Qtree` package (http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/qtree/) as recommended here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex (however the lines are straight and not horizontal/vertical as in your sketch)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to add the labels on the left hand side (Class, Family, ...)?  Also I would like the style of connectors as shown above.

If anyone's still game, could they please show me the code, as I am still learning.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this sort of tree easily with the [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) package:

In the code below, the labels are created using a tree with branches that are not actually drawn (using a style `blank` which sets `[draw=none]`). This ensures that they line up with the levels of the main tree.  By putting two trees as nodes in a matrix we achieve a reasonable separation between the labels and the main tree.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
-- +(0,-8pt)
-| (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
{
\node{\Tree
    [.Class  \edge[blank]; 
    [.Order  \edge[blank];
    [.Family \edge[blank]; 
    [.Genus ]]]]};
&
\node{\Tree 
 [.{$\gamma$-proteobacteria} 
    [.Alteromonadales 
        [.Alteromonadaceae  {Glaciecola}  Alteromonas Agarivorans ] ]
    [.Vibrionales [.Vibrionacae Vibrio ]]]};\\
};           
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to create a bit more distance between the labels on the left hand side (Class, Order, ...) and the graph?

Comment: @ptrcao I've modified the example to make two trees in a matrix of nodes instead of one tree.  This gives more space between the labels, since the labels are no longer connected to the main tree.

Answer (score 10):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\def\psedge{\ncangles[angleA=-90,angleB=90]}
\psset{levelsep=14mm,treesep=1.75cm,nodesep=3pt}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{1.3cm}
\pstree{\Tr[name=class]{$\gamma$-proteobacteria}}{%
  \pstree{\Tr[name=order]{Alteromonadales}}{%
    \pstree[thistreesep=3mm]{\Tr[name=family]{Alteromonadaceae}}{%
       \Tr[name=genus]{Glaciecola}
       \Tr{Alteromonas} 
       \Tr{Agarivorans}%
  }}
  \pstree{\Tr{Vibrionales}}{%
    \pstree{\Tr{Vibrionacae}}{%
      \Tr{Vibrio}
  }}
}

\rput[rc](0,0|class){Class}\rput[rc](0,0|order){Order}%
\rput[rc](0,0|family){Family}\rput[rc](0,0|genus){Genus}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any way to offset the Alteromonas branch slightly?  I'm not sure if it's necessary but I see it often being done in biology and I'm tempted to think it's deliberate, to avoid giving that branch the appearance of receiving special treatment or greater relational weight, relative to the others...

Comment: all can be set locally by `thistreesep` or `thislevelsep`

Comment: @Herbert I'm sorry for being a nuisance, can you please show explicitly?  I'm really new at this!  :|

Comment: @ptrcao: then tell me what _exactly_ should be modified. For example: `    \pstree[thistreesep=11mm]{\Tr[name=family]{Alteromonadaceae}}{%`

Comment: The line extending down to Alteromonas has to be offset by a couple of mm - right or left, it doesn't matter.  This is so that it is deliberately misaligned with the vertical line directly above it descending from Alteromonadaceae.  If this is confusing, just look at the image in the OP, and take it literally rather than by accident that the Alteromonas branch is slight misaligned...  Thanks.

Comment: See also the alternative solution above where the vertical line is offset in the described manner.  Thanks.

Comment: @ptrcao: ah that's simple, see edited answer

Comment: @Herbert Brilliant, thanks. :)  Last request - is there a way to make it work with latexmk?  I never really use xelatex and don't even know what it's for.  Ultimately, my bibliographies need latexmk to be properly compiled...

Comment: @ptrcao: insert `-shell-escape` after the `%O` and load package `autp-pst-pdf` (`$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 %O -shell-escape %S/`). You have to insert  a new entry (+) move it up and then delete the old one. It makes sense that you have installed Perl (http://www.actibestate.com/perl/) then the very useful program  `pdfcrop` can be used.