# Suggestions for an automatic taxonomy environment

Tags: macros, environments, environment-variables

[image: MNWE]

**Background**

In this site there are excellent examples of 
[How to draw up a hierarchical tree diagram for taxonomic classification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19029/how-to-draw-up-a-hierarchical-tree-diagram-for-taxonomic-classification) of several groups but often you must show only the position of a concrete group or single species across a long classification. Then a tree is not useful. A solution is simply show the ordered taxons in plain text:

```
Class Mammalia C. Linnaeus, 1758
Order Primates C. Linnaeus, 1758
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) 
Family Hominidae  Gray, 1825
Genus Homo C. Linnaeus, 1758
Homo sapiens  C. Linnaeus, 1758
```

This is correct, but usually is showed with a hierarchical indentation that make a slopping margin (that looks much better and it is easier to follow IMHO):

```
Class Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758
 Order Primates Linnaeus, 1758
  Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) 
   Family Hominidae  Gray, 1825
    Genus Homo Linnaeus, 1758
     Species Homo sapiens Linnaeus, 1758
```

Obtain the above manually in LaTeX is easy, but it could look much better if the scientific names are also indented in parallel to the left margin. Make this manually is possible with a tabular environments, so you can obtain:

```
Class           Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758
 Order           Primates Linnaeus, 1758
  Superfamily     Hominoidea (Gray, 1825)
   Family          Hominidae  Gray, 1825
    Genus           Homo Linnaeus, 1758
     Especies        Homo sapiens Linnaeus, 1758
```

But need a lot of typing and any taxon as `Mammalia` must be at the right of all the groups levels (`Family`,`Genus`, etc.). This could be fine in one column with this example but in a long classifications (20-25 lines) or a two column document, the horizontal space is limited, and then it is better start  `Mamalia` at the left of the end of `Species`:

```
Class        Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758
  Order        Primates Linnaeus, 1758
    Superfamily  Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) 
      Family       Hominidae Gray, 1825
        Genus        Homo Linnaeus, 1758
          Species      Homo sapiens Linnaeus, 1758
```

And reduce the indentation length as needed:

```
Class        Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758
 Order        Primates Linnaeus, 1758
  Superfamily  Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) 
   Family       Hominidae Gray, 1825
    Genus        Homo Linnaeus, 1758
     Species      Homo sapiens Linnaeus, 1758
```

As this cannot be done (easily) within a table, I think in a environment to make this (more or less) "automagically".

**Desired goals**

Ideally, the environment (or any other approach) should work without typing any (= as less as possible) LaTeX command in the plain text:

```
\begin{taxonomy}
Class Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758
Order Primates Linnaeus, 1758
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) 
Family Hominidae Gray, 1825
Genus Homo Linnaeus, 1758
Homo sapiens  Linnaeus, 1758
\end{taxonomy}
```

And:

- Do not break any line as far it is possible without reducing the font size. That is, if text of some line take more than  `1\linewidth` with the default spacing, this spacing must be reduced to a reasonable value.
- If the whole environment take less than `\linewidth`, it must be centered (without losing the format, obviously).

But this is my naive attempt so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}

\newcounter{line}
\def\doline#1{\addtocounter{line}{1}\hspace{\value{line}\parindent}#1}

\def\marker{\end{taxonomicon}}
{\obeylines
\gdef\getlines#1
  {\def\text{#1}%
  \ifx\text\marker \let\next\text
    \else \doline{#1}\let\next\getlines \fi
  \next}}
\newenvironment{taxonomicon}{\sffamily\hfill\begingroup\obeylines\getlines}%
  {\setcounter{line}{0}\endgroup}

\newcommand\taxon[2]{
\makebox[7em][l]{\color{gray}#1\dotfill}
#2
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

% poor man's version

\parindent=1.7em % adjust as needed

\begin{taxonomicon} 
Class Mammalia C. Linnaeus, 1758
Order Primates C. Linnaeus, 1758
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) 
Family Hominidae  Gray, 1825
Genus Homo C. Linnaeus, 1758
Homo sapiens  C. Linnaeus, 1758

\end{taxonomicon}

\lipsum[2]

\parindent=1.2em % adjust as needed

\begin{taxonomicon} 
\taxon{Class}{Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758}
\taxon{Order}{Primates Linnaeus, 1758}
\taxon{Superfamily}{Hominoidea (Gray, 1825)}
\taxon{Family}{Hominidae  Gray, 1825}
\taxon{Genus}{Homo Linnaeus, 1758}
\taxon{Species}{Homo sapiens} Linnaeus, 1758

\end{taxonomicon}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Note: I asking only a solution for a classification that  always descend 1 level in each line (no matter of the real meaning of the text), but suggestion for more complex classifications (with two families, and several genera, for example) would be wonderful.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154976/11604 was my own solution with a very different approach to the accepted answer. I do not posted here because add elements not included in the question, but is indeed a related answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your specifications are quite complicated. Here's a non complete solution where the second parts will always start right of the longest first part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{taxonomy}{O{1em}}
 {
  \begin{center}
  \taxon_get_line:
 }
 {
  \taxon_print:n { #1 }
  \end{center}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_taxon_item_seq
\seq_new:N \l_taxon_itemsA_seq
\seq_new:N \l_taxon_itemsB_seq
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_indent_dim
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_default_indent_dim
\box_new:N \l_taxon_item_box

\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_get_line:
 {
  \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NF \end { \taxon_get_line:w }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_get_line:w #1 \\
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_taxon_items_seq { ~ } { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_taxon_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_right:NV \l_taxon_itemsA_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_taxon_itemsB_seq { \seq_use:Nn \l_taxon_items_seq { ~ } }
  \taxon_get_line:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_print:n #1
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l_taxon_indent_dim
  \dim_set:Nn \l_taxon_default_indent_dim { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_taxon_itemsA_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_taxon_item_box { \hspace{ \l_taxon_indent_dim } ##1 }
    \dim_compare:nT { \l_taxon_width_dim < \box_wd:N \l_taxon_item_box }
     {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_taxon_width_dim { \box_wd:N \l_taxon_item_box }
     }
    \dim_add:Nn \l_taxon_indent_dim { \l_taxon_default_indent_dim }
   }
  \dim_add:Nn \l_taxon_width_dim { \l_taxon_default_indent_dim }
  \dim_zero:N \l_taxon_indent_dim
  \leavevmode
  \vbox:n
   {
    \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l_taxon_itemsA_seq \l_taxon_itemsB_seq \taxon_print_line:nn
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_print_line:nn #1 #2
 {
  \hbox:n { \hspace{ \l_taxon_indent_dim } \makebox[\l_taxon_width_dim][l]{#1\dotfill}#2 }
  \dim_add:Nn \l_taxon_indent_dim { \l_taxon_default_indent_dim }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{taxonomy}
Class Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Order Primates Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) \\
Family Hominidae Gray, 1825 \\
Genus Homo Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Species Homo sapiens  Linnaeus, 1758 \\
\end{taxonomy}

\begin{taxonomy}[.5em]
Class Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Order Primates Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) \\
Family Hominidae Gray, 1825 \\
Genus Homo Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Species Homo sapiens  Linnaeus, 1758 \\
\end{taxonomy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Adding a “backing up” correction

The idea in a comment can be implemented by adding a second optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{taxonomy}{O{1em}O{0pt}}
 {
  \begin{center}
  \taxon_get_line:
 }
 {
  \taxon_print:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \end{center}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_taxon_item_seq
\seq_new:N \l_taxon_itemsA_seq
\seq_new:N \l_taxon_itemsB_seq
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_indent_dim
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_default_indent_dim
\dim_new:N \l_taxon_corr_dim
\box_new:N \l_taxon_item_box

\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_get_line:
 {
  \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NF \end { \taxon_get_line:w }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_get_line:w #1 \\
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_taxon_items_seq { ~ } { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_taxon_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_right:NV \l_taxon_itemsA_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_taxon_itemsB_seq { \seq_use:Nn \l_taxon_items_seq { ~ } }
  \taxon_get_line:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_print:nn #1 #2
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l_taxon_indent_dim
  \dim_set:Nn \l_taxon_default_indent_dim { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_taxon_corr_dim { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_taxon_itemsA_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_taxon_item_box { \hspace{ \l_taxon_indent_dim } ##1 }
    \dim_compare:nT { \l_taxon_width_dim < \box_wd:N \l_taxon_item_box }
     {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_taxon_width_dim { \box_wd:N \l_taxon_item_box }
     }
    \dim_add:Nn \l_taxon_indent_dim { \l_taxon_default_indent_dim }
   }
  \dim_add:Nn \l_taxon_width_dim { \l_taxon_default_indent_dim }
  \dim_zero:N \l_taxon_indent_dim
  \leavevmode
  \vbox:n
   {
    \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l_taxon_itemsA_seq \l_taxon_itemsB_seq \taxon_print_line:nn
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \taxon_print_line:nn #1 #2
 {
  \hbox:n
   {
    \hspace{ \l_taxon_indent_dim }
    \makebox[\l_taxon_width_dim][l]{#1\dotfill\hspace{ -\l_taxon_corr_dim }}
    \hspace{ \l_taxon_corr_dim }
    #2
   }
  \dim_add:Nn \l_taxon_indent_dim { \l_taxon_default_indent_dim }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{taxonomy}
Class Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Order Primates Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) \\
Family Hominidae Gray, 1825 \\
Genus Homo Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Species Homo sapiens  Linnaeus, 1758 \\
\end{taxonomy}

\begin{taxonomy}[2em][-6em]
Class Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Order Primates Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Superfamily Hominoidea (Gray, 1825) \\
Family Hominidae Gray, 1825 \\
Genus Homo Linnaeus, 1758 \\
Species Homo sapiens  Linnaeus, 1758 \\
\end{taxonomy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are complicated, that's why I asked. `;-)` Joking aside, although the solution is not complete, I take my hat off to you for the solved parts. With values ​​between 0.3-1em (which seem reasonable for a normal text) the result is quite elegant and compact anyway. The problem is mainly with higher values​​, as 2em, because then the dotted space become too long.

Comment: For a setting of `2em`, the change of  `\makebox[\l_taxon_width_dim][l]{#1\dotfill}}#2}` to `\makebox[\l_taxon_width_dim][l]{#1\dotfill\hspace{6em}}\hspace{-6em}#2}` is near to I want. But with `1em` the added spaces must be only about `2em` and `-2em`, etc. Now the point is only how to find automatically a reasonable `\hspace`s for each setting.