# Recursion Tree in LaTeX

Tags: trees

How can the following recursion tree be drawn in LaTeX?

[image: wanted]

I have tried using Ti*k*Z pictures for this, but I continue to get errors in the code. Please suggest an easier code for the same.

Comment: Show us your code; this is not a 'please do it for me' site.

Comment: Can you post the code you've got? How can we suggest easier code if we don't know what you are using right now?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package; you can even leave the content calculations to the package:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south,
  s sep=2pt
},
delay={for descendants={
  if n=1
    {draw,content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args=
      {$c\binom{n}{#2}^{2}$}{content}{int(2^level)}}
      {if n'=1{draw,content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args=
        {$c\binom{n}{#2}^{2}$}{content}{int(2^level)}}{}
      },  
     where n children={0}{draw,content=c}{}
  }
}
[$cn^{2}$,draw
  [
    [
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
    [
      [,phantom]
    ]
    [
      [,phantom]
    ]
    [
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [
    [,phantom [,phantom]]
  ]
  [
    [,phantom [,phantom]]
  ]
  [
    [
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
    [
      [,phantom]
    ]
    [
      [,phantom]
    ]
    [
      [
         []
        []
        []
     ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
      ]
      [
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the answer? It's highly likely that the person asking the question hasn't made any effort at all and just want someone to do his/her work for him/her, even though something else is said.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Why not? I'd say 70% or more of the questions here follow your rule. Acoording to that, this site would be full of unanswered questions.

Comment: Well, because this is _not_ a "please do it for me" site, as far as I know. `:-)` (At least that was what I was told when I joined the community a few years ago.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I've been here more than you and I'm pretty convinced that basically this *is* a do it for me site, even if sometimes we try to think it's not :) And I see no problem with that.

Answer (score 4):

`forest` allows you to specify a tree using standard bracket notation. See [my answer to an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex/254926#254926) for an explanation of how to turn a tree into a specification using bracket notation. Other answers there cover other packages suitable for drawing simple trees (as specified in the question). So if you don't like `forest`, perhaps one of the others will suit.

For `forest`, here's a prototype to get you started:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    align=center
  }
  [root
    [child
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
      [grandchild, calign with current]
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
    ]
    [child
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
      [grandchild, calign with current]
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
    ]
    [child
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
      [grandchild, calign with current]
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
    ]
    [child
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
      [grandchild, calign with current]
      [grandchild
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
        [great\\-grandchild]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image: prototype]