# Error while Trying to draw a Recursion Tree?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
   draw,
   align=center
}
[TowersOfHanoi\left 4, 1, 3, 2\right
[TowersOfHanoi\left 3, 1, 2, 3\right
  [TowersOfHanoi\left 2, 1, 3, 2\right
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 1, 2, 3\right]
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 2, 3, 1\right]
  ]
  [TowersOfHanoi\left 2, 3, 2, 1\right
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 3, 1, 2\right]
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 1, 2, 3\right]
  ]
]
[TowersOfHanoi\left 3, 2, 3, 1\right
  [TowersOfHanoi\left 2, 2, 1, 3\right
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 2, 3, 1\right]
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1 ,3, 1, 2\right]
  ]
  [TowersOfHanoi\left 2, 1, 3, 2\right
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 1, 2, 3\right]
    [TowersOfHanoi\left 1, 2, 3, 1\right]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
>   to be read again
>  
>                      \right
>  
>   l.32 \end{forest}
>
> ?

What am I doing wrong?

---

<sup>Note: The above code is a slightly modified version of this [benchmark code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257587/recursion-tree-in-latex) which reproduces the drawing.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the commas. A comma means that the text of the node is ended, and options pertaining to it follows. To have commas in the node text, wrap it in braces.

Second, `\left`/`\right`. They require math mode, and they also require a delimiter to follow them, which you've forgotten. I'd remove them altogether though, and insert just `(`/`)` instead. `\left .. \right` isn't needed when you only have numbers between them like that.

As noted in a comment below, `align=center` doesn't really do much useful here, so unless you're planning to, for example, add linebreaks, it can be removed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
   draw
}
[{TowersOfHanoi(4, 1, 3, 2)}
[{TowersOfHanoi(3, 1, 2, 3)}
  [{TowersOfHanoi(2, 1, 3, 2)}
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
  ]
  [{TowersOfHanoi(2, 3, 2, 1)}
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 3, 1, 2)}]
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
  ]
]
[{TowersOfHanoi(3, 2, 3, 1)}
  [{TowersOfHanoi(2, 2, 1, 3)}
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1 ,3, 1, 2)}]
  ]
  [{TowersOfHanoi(2, 1, 2, 2)}
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
    [{TowersOfHanoi(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

That said, your tree becomes very wide when you write `TowersOfHanoi` in every node. Perhaps you could consider abbreviating it to `ToH`, or leaving it out altogether.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
   draw,
}
[{ToH(4, 1, 3, 2)},label={above:ToH = TowersOfHanoi}
[{ToH(3, 1, 2, 3)}
  [{ToH(2, 1, 3, 2)}
    [{ToH(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
    [{ToH(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
  ]
  [{ToH(2, 3, 2, 1)}
    [{ToH(1, 3, 1, 2)}]
    [{ToH(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
  ]
]
[{ToH(3, 2, 3,1)}
  [{ToH(2, 2, 1, 3)}
    [{ToH(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
    [{ToH(1, 3, 1, 2)}]
  ]
  [{ToH(2, 1, 2, 2)}
    [{ToH(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
    [{ToH(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
   draw,
}
[{(4, 1, 3, 2)},label={above:Arguments to TowersOfHanoi}
[{(3, 1, 2, 3)}
  [{(2, 1, 3, 2)}
    [{(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
    [{(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
  ]
  [{(2, 3, 2, 1)}
    [{(1, 3, 1, 2)}]
    [{(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
  ]
]
[{(3, 2, 3,1)}
  [{(2, 2, 1, 3)}
    [{(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
    [{(1, 3, 1, 2)}]
  ]
  [{(2, 1, 2, 2)}
    [{(1, 1, 2, 3)}]
    [{(1, 2, 3, 1)}]
  ]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `align=center` isn't doing much either. (It is adding a little vertical padding.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You are right, reducing the text is a good idea.