# Tikz vertical levels instead of horizontal

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

The following code :

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, drop shadow, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   fill=green!30},
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=blue!10},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=green!10}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=500mm},
  level 2/.append style={sibling distance=160mm},
  edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
  >=latex]

% root of the the initial tree, level 1
\node[root] {\Huge Fuselage}
% The first level, as children of the initial tree
  child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (ch1) {\huge Functions}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c1) {\Large Shell containing payload}}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c2) {\Large Protection against climate}}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c3) {\Large Central structural member}}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c4) {\Large Houses aircraft systems}}
  }
  child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (ch2) {\huge Requirements}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c5) {\Large Low drag}}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c6) {\Large Structural}}
    child {node[level 2, yshift=-30pt] (c7) {\Large Costs}}
  };

% The second level, relatively positioned nodes
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
\node [below = of  c1, xshift=60pt] (c11) {Rapid loading Huge and unloading};

\node [below = of  c2, xshift=30pt] (c21) {Low temperatures};
\node [below = of  c21] (c22) {Low pressures};
\node [below = of  c22] (c23) {High wind speeds};

\node [below = of  c4, xshift=20pt] (c41) {Electrical};
\node [below = of  c41] (c42) {Undercarriage};

\node [below = of  c6, xshift=20pt] (c61) {Strong};
\node [below = of  c61] (c62) {Rigid};
\node [below = of  c62] (c63) {Light};
\node [below = of  c63] (c64) {Fixed useful life};

\node [below = of  c7, xshift=75pt] (c71) { Minimise operating costs};
\node [below = of  c71] (c72) {Maximise earning capacity};

\end{scope}

% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
\foreach \value in {1,...,1}
  \draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c1\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,3}
  \draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,2}
  \draw[->] (c4.195) |- (c4\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
  \draw[->] (c6.195) |- (c6\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,2}
  \draw[->] (c7.195) |- (c7\value.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces this tree diagram:

[image]

Note that the third level is spread out horizontally.

Is there a way to have the third level also be distributed vertically, like the fourth level? The result I'm looking for should have this structure:

[image]

Comment: See http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/, there the first example is very similar to your problem There you only need to ad next level of diagram on the way as it is designed last one.

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses `forest` to move things around. All of this is packed into a style which makes it possible to specify the tree itself very concisely.

[image: direction switch style]

The tree itself is specified in bracket syntax:

```
  [Fuselage
    [Functions
      [Shell containing payload
        [Rapid loading and unloading
        ]
      ]
      [Protection against climate
        [Low temperatures
        ]
        [Low pressures
        ]
        [High wind speeds
        ]
      ]
      [Central structural member
      ]
      [Houses aircraft systems
        [Electrical
        ]
        [Undercarriage
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Requirements
      [Low Drag
      ]
      [Structural
        [Strong
        ]
        [Rigid
        ]
        [Light
        ]
        [Fixed useful life
        ]
      ]
      [Costs
        [Minimise operating costs
        ]
        [Maximise earning capacity
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

This is obviously quite efficient once you get used to it, but a bit alien looking at first. For a brief introduction to this syntax and some of `forest`'s highlights, see the second part of [my answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254926/).

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,svgnames,dvipsnames,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{% this specifies a style, direction switch, which manages the layout, formatting and tweaking of the various levels and nodes of the tree itself
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={
      draw=DodgerBlue2,
      thick,
      inner ysep=2pt,
      edge={thick},
      if level=1{% the root node is level 0 so this is the layer of horizontally aligned nodes beneath it
        child anchor=north,
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-.5em) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
        for descendants={% apply to everything beneath level 1
          child anchor=west,
          align=left,
          edge path={
            \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) ++(1em,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
          },
          s sep+=2.5pt,
          fit=band,
        },
        for tree={% apply to everything in level 1 or beneath level 1
          parent anchor=south west,
          anchor=mid west,
          grow'=0,
          font=\sffamily,
          if n children=0{}{
            delay={
              prepend={[,phantom, calign with current]}
            }
          },
          before computing xy={
            l=2em
          }
        },
      }{
        if level=0{% this is the root node of the tree, level 0
          parent anchor=south,
          anchor=south,
          before drawing tree={% we repack just the top bit of the tree, right at the end, to account for the increased spacing introduced by moving things around; after repacking, we need to explicitly recompute the x-y coordinates as well, before the tree is drawn
            pack',
            compute xy,
          }
        }{},
      },
    },
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch% apply the style defined above
  % specify the content of the tree
  [Fuselage
    [Functions
      [Shell containing payload
        [Rapid loading and unloading
        ]
      ]
      [Protection against climate
        [Low temperatures
        ]
        [Low pressures
        ]
        [High wind speeds
        ]
      ]
      [Central structural member
      ]
      [Houses aircraft systems
        [Electrical
        ]
        [Undercarriage
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [Requirements
      [Low Drag
      ]
      [Structural
        [Strong
        ]
        [Rigid
        ]
        [Light
        ]
        [Fixed useful life
        ]
      ]
      [Costs
        [Minimise operating costs
        ]
        [Maximise earning capacity
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```