# How do I format text inside a node?

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees

I'm making an academic family tree and I'd like to put a couple of bullet points of info for each person. I'm just starting with LaTeX, so this is the simplest code possible:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
  \node {Manfred Kock}
    child { node {Karsten Danzmann}
      child { node {\underline{Guido Mueller} }
        child { node [draw, align=left]{\underline{Marina Longnickel} \\blah} }
        child { node {Aaron Spector} }
        child { node {James Ira Thorpe} } 
        child { node {Alix Preston} }
            }
      child { node {Oliver Jennrich} }
      child { node {Gerhard Heinzel} }
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to edit text the way one would in a Word document - underline, make bullet points, change font and size, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

I only change far left bottom node. Beside used `underline` in `tabular` environment are other possibilities which I can elaborate latter.

Code of above image is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                       draw, anchor=north, align=center,
                       top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
  \node {Manfred Kock}
    child { node {Karsten Danzmann}
      child { node {Guido Mueller}
        child { node {Marina Longnickel\\ 
                            \scriptsize
                        \begin{tabular}{l}%or c or 
                    \hline
                    \textbullet\ some additional\\
                                information about\\ 
                                person\\
                    \textbullet\ simple manual\\
                                formatting
                        \end{tabular}}}
        child { node {\underline{Aaron Spector}\\
                    \begin{minipage}{28mm}
                        \footnotesize\RaggedLeft
                        \begin{compactitem}[\textbullet]
                    \item some text
                    \item some longer text which need two lines
                        \end{compactitem}
                    \end{minipage}
                     } }
        child { node {James Ira Thorpe} }
        child { node {Alix Preston} }
            }
      child { node {Oliver Jennrich} }
      child { node {Gerhard Heinzel} }
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In above code, according to additional information received in comments, I extend my first code with two case:

- let be emphasized, that nodes top ar in-line, I add `anchor=north` in
  definition of node features.
- far left bottom node use `tabular` and `\textbullet` for additional
  text. Instead of `\underline} for line under name I use`\hline` in
  tabular,
- in the next node on right I use `minipage` and `compactitem` from package `paralist`. Here the left to setting width of `minipage`  manually, however, it can be set width of node width `text width=31mm` and then omit `minipage`

  `\node[text width=33mm]\begin{compactitem}[\textbullet] ...`

[image]

**Edit (2):**
For use in `beamer` (as follows from your comment) you need to solve, how to fit image in frame. Frame's width is about 124 mm (if recall correct). Therefore I decided to have all nodes with the same fixed width determined by `text width=22mm` and `sibling distance=26mm`. Also I select for size for main text in node `\scriptsize` and for comments in items `tiny` size. Of course, you can change this selection to your taste and wish. Obtained image is:

[image]

As you can see, now I pay attention to connection between nodes and use the same style as proposed cfr, but I still persist on pure TikZ solution.  Code for above image is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hspace*{-4mm}% for horizontal centering of image on frame
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   sibling distance = 26mm,% newmeasure
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                       draw, anchor=north, font=\scriptsize,
                       text width=22mm, align=center,% fixed width of nodes
                       top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
%edge from parent/.append style={thick},
    edge from parent fork down,
                        ]
  \node {Manfred Kock}
    child { node {Karsten Danzmann}
      child { node {Guido Mueller}
        child { node {\underline{Marina Longnickel}\\
                        \tiny\RaggedLeft
                        \begin{compactitem}[\textbullet]
                    \item some additional information about person
                    \item simple manual formatting
                        \end{compactitem}
                    } }
        child { node {\underline{Aaron Spector}\\
                        \tiny\RaggedLeft
                        \begin{compactitem}[\textbullet]
                    \item some text
                    \item some longer text which need two lines
                        \end{compactitem}
                     } }
        child { node {James Ira Thorpe} }
        child { node {Alix Preston} }
            }
      child { node {Oliver Jennrich} }
      child { node {Gerhard Heinzel} }
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: yes! Great, thank you! Is there any way to put bullet points on those?

Comment: @solamew, of course. You can put itemize inside (for this you need minipage environemt) or put `\textbullet` by hand. A bit later I will show some examples for this.

Comment: nifty! :D Also, can I define the size of each node so that text wraps around to the next line? Cuz they are starting to pile up on top of each other >.>

Comment: @Solarmew, I upgrade (about one hour ago) my answer with two cases, hot to add  text with bullets below main text.

Comment: @Solarmew, I upgrade my answer to use it in beamer frame.

Comment: How is use of `forest` *not* a 'pure TikZ solution' given that it is entirely implemented in TikZ (well PGF)? ;) Note that I already voted your answer up: I think it is good. But championing it on grounds of its purity makes me laugh. Why not just say yours is easier to understand as the approach is simpler and more straightforward?

Comment: @cfr, I'm not familiar with `forest`, so until now I avoid to use it.  Actually, for my needs I rarely use such kind of images˛ Your answer on above question (almost) convince me, that it is time to look this package closer. You really mastered it. I vote it.

Answer (score 3):

As a supplement to [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267394/39222), to avoid collisions between the edges running from parent to child and the nodes themselves as the content of the nodes expands, you might consider using the `edge from parent fork down` style:

[image: another kind of branch]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    sibling distance=10em,
    level distance=2.5em,
    every node/.style = {
      shape=rectangle,
      rounded corners,
      draw,
      align=center,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=blue!20,
      anchor=north
    },
    edge from parent/.append style={thick},
    edge from parent fork down,
  ]
  \node {Manfred Kock}
    child { node {Karsten Danzmann}
      child { node {\underline{Guido Mueller} }
        child { node [draw, align=left]{\underline{Marina Longnickel} \\blah} }
        child { node {Aaron Spector} }
        child { node {James Ira Thorpe} }
        child { node {Alix Preston} }
            }
      child { node {Oliver Jennrich} }
      child { node {Gerhard Heinzel} }
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you are interested in a more concise tree-specification syntax, then you could also use `forest` which offers a great many possibilities for customisation. Here's an example:

Here's a straight 'translation' of your original tree:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    align=center,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!20,
    anchor=north
  }
  [Manfred Kock
    [Karsten Danzmann
      [\underline{Guido Mueller}
        [\underline{Marina Longnickel}\\blah, align=left]
        [Aaron Spector]
        [James Ira Thorpe]
        [Alix Preston]
      ]
      [Oliver Jennrich]
      [Gerhard Heinzel]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

The second part of [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254926/) explains how to do the translation and briefly introduces the `forest` package, as the manual, while very thorough, can be a little overwhelming.

[image: original tree translated]

We can make this a lot fancier. Here's a version using an `academic family tree` style. This one implements code similar to the `edge from parent fork down` style. It also uses `enumitem` to demonstrate the use of various kinds of list within the tree, and a style `wrapped node=<width>` which is responsible for customising the width of a tabular array within the node. The `align=<spec>` key provided by `forest` can be simply `left` or `center` etc., but it can instead specify a tabular array. `\hline` can then replace `\underline{}` and the contents of the node can be automatically aligned left rather than the default centring and wrapped to the required width as part of the array specification. The `array` package is used so that a suitable column type can be created for this purpose. Although only one-column tabulars are used in this case, you could obviously specify multiple columns were that required.

[image: fancier academic family tree]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array,ragged2e}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{@{}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}
\newlist{treelist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[treelist,1]{nosep,wide,label=\textbullet}
\newlist{treeitems}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[treeitems,1]{nosep,labelindent=0pt,leftmargin=*,label=\textbullet}
\newlist{treeinline}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[treeinline,1]{label=(\roman*)}
\forestset{
  wrapped node/.style={
    align={P{#1}},
  },
  academic family tree/.style={
    for tree={
      rounded corners,
      draw,
      align=center,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=blue!20,
      anchor=north,
      parent anchor=south,
      edge={very thick, gray},
      drop shadow,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      if level=0{}{
        if={isodd(n_children("!u"))}{
          if={equal(n,int((n_children("!u")+1)/2))}{
            calign with current
          }{}
        }{}
      },
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  academic family tree
  [Manfred Kock
    [Karsten Danzmann
      [\underline{Guido Mueller}
        [Marina Longnickel\\\hline
        \begin{treelist}
          \item blah blah blah blah rabbits rosemary raucous rhinoceros  blabbity blah
          \item blah
          \item blah
        \end{treelist},
        wrapped node=29mm]
        [Aaron Spector\\\hline
        \begin{treeitems}
          \item This is another style of list
          \item with different indentation
          \item \dots.
        \end{treeitems},
        wrapped node=22.5mm]
        [James Ira Thorpe]
        [Alix Preston]
      ]
      [{Oliver Jennrich\\\hline
        This is an inline, ordered list with
        \begin{treeinline}
          \item a
          \item few
          \item of
          \item my
          \item favourite
          \item things
        \end{treeinline},
      },
      wrapped node=24mm
      ]
      [Gerhard Heinzel]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use this code for \documentclass{beamer}?

Comment: @minthao_2011, of course, but other question is, if the image will fit in one frame.

Comment: @minthao_2011 I'm not sure you can use `enumitem`, but the rest should be fine. You would not need the ragged right stuff, I don't think, as Beamer sets stuff ragged right anyway. `forest` works fine with Beamer, especially since it is particularly good at making quite compact trees.

Comment: Can I use the Comma in node. E.g Manfred, Kock?

Comment: @minthao_2011 Sure. But you need to put curly brackets around the node content in that case e.g. `[{Manfred, Kock}]` to stop `forest` trying to read the `Kock` as a key it should process. This is why I used them around the Oliver J node: because there's a comma in the list of items in that case, so it needs to be protected.