# tikz curves with labeled nodes as start and end points

Tags: tikz-trees, curve-fitting, pst-jtree

These days I'm typesetting a lot of trees (in the graph-theoretic sense) using `pst-jtree`, which is essentially a collection of macros over `pstricks`. So, I might have the following.

```
\jtree
   \! = {A}! .
   \! = <left>[xunit=5em]{B}!b ^<right>[xunit=5em]{E}!c .
   \!b = : {m} {C} : {n} {D} : {o} {p} .
   \!c = : {q} {F} : {r} {G} : {s} {t} .
\endjtree
```

[image]

These are the easy cases. Sometimes I need to draw a vertex between nodes that are some distance apart. I usually do it with `\nccurve`, which is neat in the sense that I can use `@` labels (or alternatively `\rnode`) to define the start-end points of a Bezier curve, and then manipulate it with `angleA`, `angleB`, and `ncurv`.

```
\jtree
   \! = {A}! .
   \! = <left>[xunit=5em]{B}!b ^<right>[xunit=5em]{E}!c .
   \!b = : {m} {C} : {n} {D}@D !d .
   \!c = : {q} {F} : {r} {G} : {s} {t}@t .
   \!d = <left>{o} .
\endjtree
\nccurve[angleA=-45,angleB=90,ncurvA=1.2,ncurvB=1.6]{-}{D:b}{t:t}
```

[image]

However, when trees get to a certain level of complexity, I want to have more control over my curves than I can get with `\nccurve` (for example, with `\nccurve` sometimes I have to choose between a curve that crosses over node labels (ugh) or one that has really tight and long arcs (ugh again)).

To me, the obvious solution is to use `tikz` to define a set of n points and then have it draw a smoothed curve over it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) (2,-2) (3,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However, I don't know how to combine these two strategies. The main problem is that (as far as I know) `\draw` requires me to define `(x,y)` coordinates, rather than referring to `@` or `\rnode` labels. Is there a way around this? Specifically, I want to be able to write something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates { (D:b) (1,1) (2,-2) (t:t)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The idea being that `(0,0)` is set to the bottom of the `D` label, `(t:t)` is set whatever `(x,y)` coordinate relative to `(0,0)`, and then `(1,1)` and `(2,-2)` are set relative to `(0,0)`, as usual.

Comment: The first step would be to switch from pstricks to tikz-qtree.  Then you might be able to use tikz coordinates from the tree.

Comment: Or `forest`. If you are typesetting complex trees, `forest` is more powerful than `tikz-qtree`, as I understand it. Both give you the full power of TikZ but `forest` allows you to manipulate the tree in various ways, to use relative nodes names and node walks etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `forest`, you can draw the curve by specifying it as part of the tree. Here, I use the current node's parent anchor (`(.parent anchor)`) as a value for `shift` so that the coordinates for the plot can be specified relative to that anchor. I then use the child anchor of a named node, `t` (`(t.child anchor)`) to specify the end point for the curve.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\newlength\myex
\settoheight{\myex}{X}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    anchor=mid,
    text height=\myex,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
    s sep+=15pt,
  }
  [A
    [B
      [m]
      [C
        [n]
        [D, tikz={
          \draw [shift=(.parent anchor)] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates { (0,0) +(1.25,-.5) +(2.5,1) (t.child anchor)};
        }
          [o]
          [,phantom]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [E
      [q]
      [F
        [r]
        [G
          [s]
          [t, name=t]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: plotted curve in <code>forest</code> tree]

The manual for `forest` is good but a little intense at times. A brief introduction can be found in the second part of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254926/) to a related question. This explains how to specify a tree using the bracket notation and introduces some basic features of the package.