# Highlight areas in tikz-tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-trees

### Problem

I am looking for the basic approach to achieve the below result in a tikz-environment. Currently I have the tree-part of the graphic below. How, in general, do I add highlighted areas (the blue and green ones) such as in the picture below to a tikz-tree?

Bonus: Should I even be using a tikz-tree?

### Steps taken

I have found [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree) and [Highlighting/marking areas in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277649/highlighting-marking-areas-in-a-tikz-tree), but they do not seem to be applicable to my problem.

### Target Output

[image]

### Current Progress

This is my progress so far, if you want to show the approach by an example.

[image]

### Source (if needed)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, shapes}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling angle=90, shape = rectangle, minimum size=1.5em]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling angle=45, shape = rectangle, minimum size=1em]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling angle=22.5, shape = rectangle, minimum size=0.5em]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw, very thin]

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow cyclic,
  shape = circle,
  level distance=3em,
  triangle/.style = {fill=blue!20, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3 },                    
                    border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180}
]
\node[triangle, border rotated, minimum size=3em] {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {black, black, black, black}
    { node {} child [color=\B] foreach \B in {black, black, black}
        { node {} child [color=\C] foreach \C in {black, black, black}
            { node {} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take my previous answer (which is essentially stolen from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539395), then it is very easy.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\newcount\tikzcountchildi
\newcount\tikzcountchildii
\newcount\tikzcountchildiii
\newcount\tikzcountchildiv
\newcount\tikzcountchildv
\newcount\tikzcountchildvi
\tikzset{garlic growth/.style={growth function=\tikz@grow@garlic,
/tikz/mmap/name=#1,mmap/#1/.is family,
mmap/initialize counts,
execute at end scope={%
\tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-i}{\the\tikzcountchildi}%
\tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-ii}{\the\tikzcountchildii}%
\tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-iii}{\the\tikzcountchildiii}%
\tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-iv}{\the\tikzcountchildiv}%
\tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-v}{\the\tikzcountchildv}%
\tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-vi}{\the\tikzcountchildvi}}},
mmap/.cd,initialize counts/.code={\tikzcountchildi=0%
\tikzcountchildii=0%
\tikzcountchildiii=0%
\tikzcountchildiv=0%
\tikzcountchildv=0%
\tikzcountchildvi=0%
}
}
\def\tikz@mmap@store@aux#1#2{%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\expandafter\xdef\noexpand\csname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\string\endcsname{#2}}}%
\def\tikz@mmap@get@from@aux#1#2{%
\ifcsname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\endcsname
\edef#2{\csname pgfk@/tikz/mmap/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/name}/#1\endcsname}%
\else
\edef#2{0}%
\fi
}

\newcount\tikzcountgrandchild
\def\tikz@grow@garlic{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall rotation}}%
  \ifcase\tikztreelevel 
  \or
   \global\advance\tikzcountchildi by1\relax%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-i}{\myni}%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-ii}{\mynii}%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-1-\the\tikzcountchildi}{\mynall}%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{p-1-\the\tikzcountchildi}{\mypi}%
   \ifnum\mynii>0
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfutil@tempa+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}%
        *(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/child weight}*(\mypi)*360/\mynii+%
            (1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/child weight})*(\tikzcountchildi-1)*360/\myni)}%
   \fi
  \or
   \global\advance\tikzcountchildii by1\relax%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-ii}{\mynii}%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-1-1}{\mynall}%
   \ifnum\mynii>0
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfutil@tempa+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}%
    *(\tikzcountchildii-1-\mynall/2)*360/\mynii}%
   \fi
   \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=1\relax
    \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-1-\the\tikzcountchildi}{\the\tikznumberofchildren}%
    \tikz@mmap@store@aux{p-1-\the\tikzcountchildi}{\the\numexpr\tikzcountchildii-1}%
    \tikz@mmap@store@aux{a-1-\the\tikzcountchildi-\the\tikzcountchildii}{\pgfutil@tempa}%
   \fi   
  \or
   \global\advance\tikzcountchildiii by1\relax%
   \ifnum\tikznumberofcurrentchild=1\relax
    \tikz@mmap@store@aux{n-1-\the\tikzcountchildi-\the\tikzcountchildii}{\the\tikznumberofchildren}%
    \tikz@mmap@store@aux{p-1-\the\tikzcountchildi-\the\tikzcountchildii}{\the\numexpr\tikzcountchildiii-1}%
   \fi   
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-iii}{\myniii}%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{a-1-1-1}{\bettera}%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-1-1-1}{\mynall}%
   \ifdim\bettera pt=0pt\relax
   \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\bettera}%
   \fi
   \ifnum\myniii>0
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfutil@tempa+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}%
     *(\tikzcountchildiii-1-\mynall/2)*360/\myniii}%
   \fi  
  \or
   \global\advance\tikzcountchildiv by1\relax%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-iv}{\myniv}%
   \ifnum\myniv>0
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfutil@tempa+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*(\tikzcountchildiv-1)*360/\myniv}%
   \fi  
  \or
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-v}{\mynv}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfutil@tempa+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/sign}*(\tikzcountchildv-1)*360/\mynv}%
   \ifnum\mynv>0
    \global\advance\tikzcountchildv by1\relax%
   \fi
  \or
   \global\advance\tikzcountchildvi by1\relax%
   \tikz@mmap@get@from@aux{n-vi}{\mynvi}%
   \ifnum\myvi>0
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgfutil@tempa}{\pgfutil@tempa+(\tikzcountchildvi-1)*360/\mynvi}%
   \fi  
  \fi
  \pgftransformreset% 
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall xshift}}%
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mmap/overall yshift}}}%
  \pgftransformrotate{\pgfutil@tempa}%
  \pgftransformxshift{\the\tikzleveldistance}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikzset{mmap/.cd,
    name/.initial=undef,
    overall rotation/.initial=0,
    overall xshift/.initial=0pt,
    overall yshift/.initial=0pt,
    sign/.initial=1,
    child weight/.initial=0.5,
    /tikz/.cd,
    Xshift/.style={xshift=#1,mmap/overall xshift=#1},
    Yshift/.style={yshift=#1,mmap/overall yshift=#1},
    branch color/.style={
        concept color=#1!80,ball color=#1!50,
        every child/.append style={concept color=#1!50},
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[garlic growth=A,mmap/child weight=0,
            mmap/overall rotation=15,mmap/sign=-1,
  shape = circle,
            level 1/.style={shape = rectangle, minimum size=1.5em,
                level distance=1.2cm,
            },
            level 2/.style={shape = rectangle, minimum size=1em,
                level distance=2.4cm,
            },
            level 3/.style={shape = rectangle, minimum size=0.5em,
                level distance=3.6cm,sibling angle=40,
            },
  edge from parent/.style={draw, very thin},nodes=fill,
  level distance=3em,
  triangle/.style = {fill=blue!50, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3 },                    
                    border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180}
]
\node[triangle, border rotated, minimum size=3em] (M){} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {black, black, black, black}
    { node {} child [color=\B] foreach \B in {black, black, black}
        { node {} child [color=\C] foreach \C in {black, black, black}
            { node {} }
        }
    };
\begin{scope}[on background layer]  
\fill[blue!20] (M.center) circle[radius=4.2cm];
\draw[yellow!50,line width=3.2em,line cap=round] (M-1.center) -- (M-1-1.center);    
\draw[yellow!50,line width=2.2em,line cap=round] (M-1-1.center) -- (M-1-1-2.center);    
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you name the nodes, you do not need to guess their indices. And of course you can write macros or styles that make the line width depend on the level, and so on.

Comment: Very nice ! Love your style M Pinguin.

Comment: Thanks again. If you are interested in the outcome, visit page 1 and 4 on  [here](https://www.ronpub.com/OJIOT_2021v7i1n06_Giouroukis.pdf)