# Drawing tree with arrow that indicates height

Tags: trees

I'm trying to create the following tree with tikz-tree, but don't how to add the arrow that indicates height. Please help.

[image: Tree]

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should show the community a little effort.

Comment: Post the code for the tree and somebody will surely be happy to show how to add the arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses an experimental package, **justtrees**, based on **forest**. More specifically, it uses version 0.5. Please ask if you wish to use it. I am really using questions here to test it, but I can provide the code to the foolhardy. (An older version is around here somewhere but won't suffice for this example.)

One key advantage of **forest** is the conciseness with which trees may be specified in the source. **justtrees** is a wrapper for **forest** designed to support easy annotations to the left and right of the tree.

The `justtree` environment takes one mandatory argument. This may be empty. Otherwise it specifies the preamble for the tree and may be used to customise the contents and formatting.

```
\begin{justtree}
  {
    <preamble, if required>
  }
  <tree specification in forest's bracket notation>
\end{justtree}
```

A basic introduction to **forest** and instructions for specifying trees using its bracket notation are provided in the second part of [my answer to a general tree-drawing question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex/254926?s=4|1.6624#254926).

The actual specification for the tree in this case is simply this:

```
  [, annotate
    [
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
    ]
    [, annotate
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [, annotate
        [[, annotate]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

The preamble for the tree does most of the work.

Shift annotations right to make room for the arrows:

```
    just format={xshift=1.5em},
```

Create a style, `annotate` for levels which should have annotations and arrows:

```
    annotate/.style={% style should be applied to the rightmost node at each level for which an arrow and annotation is required
      if level=1{% first level of tree (apparent root - the real root is added automatically at level 0)
        right just=$cn^2$,
      }{
        if n children=0{% terminal nodes
          right just=$\Theta(n^{\log_43})$
        }{% other nodes (if annotated)
          right just/.wrap pgfmath arg={$(\frac{3}{16})^##1cn^##1$}{level()},
        },
      },
      tikz+/.wrap pgfmath arg={\draw [->] (.east) -- (right just ##1.west);}{level()},
    },
```

For terminal nodes, we change the level distance for the node and its parent, use a dotted edge for the node and no edge for the parent:

```
    where n children=0{
      !u.no edge,
      !u.l sep-=10pt,
      l sep-=5pt,
      edge={dotted},
    }{},
```

Make the contents of all nodes within the tree use maths mode:

```
    for tree={
      math content,
```

Specify the content of nodes in the tree and draw the arrow at the left and the curly bracket at the bottom:

```
      delay={
        if level=1{
          content=cn^2,
          tikz+={
            \draw [<->] (!F.south west) +(-2.5em,0) coordinate (c) -- (.north -| c) node [midway, fill=white] {$\log_4n$};
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (!F.south west) -- (!L.south east) node [midway, below] {$n^{\log_43}$};
          },
        }{
          if n children=0{% terminal nodes have different content
            content=T(1),
            delay={% their parents have no content - delay this so it overwrites the specification below
              !u.content=,
            }
          }{% non-terminal nodes
            if level=0{}{% which are not at level 0 (the real root, automatically added by the justtree style)
              content/.wrap pgfmath arg={c(\frac{n}{#1})^2}{int(4^(level("!u")))},
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
  }
```

The result with `justtrees.sty` looks like this:

[image: just a tree, really]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{justtrees}% version 0.5
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{justtree}
  {
    just format={xshift=1.5em},
    annotate/.style={% style should be applied to the rightmost node at each level for which an arrow and annotation is required
      if level=1{
        right just=$cn^2$,
      }{
        if n children=0{
          right just=$\Theta(n^{\log_43})$
        }{
          right just/.wrap pgfmath arg={$(\frac{3}{16})^##1cn^##1$}{level()},
        },
      },
      tikz+/.wrap pgfmath arg={\draw [->] (.east) -- (right just ##1.west);}{level()},
    },
    where n children=0{
      !u.no edge,
      !u.l sep-=10pt,
      l sep-=5pt,
      edge={dotted},
    }{},
    for tree={
      math content,
      delay={
        if level=1{
          content=cn^2,
          tikz+={
            \draw [<->] (!F.south west) +(-2.5em,0) coordinate (c) -- (.north -| c) node [midway, fill=white] {$\log_4n$};
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, mirror}] (!F.south west) -- (!L.south east) node [midway, below] {$n^{\log_43}$};
          },
        }{
          if n children=0{
            content=T(1),
            delay={
              !u.content=,
            }
          }{
            if level=0{}{
              content/.wrap pgfmath arg={c(\frac{n}{#1})^2}{int(4^(level("!u")))},
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
  }
  [, annotate
    [
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
    ]
    [, annotate
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [
        [[]]
      ]
      [, annotate
        [[, annotate]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{justtree}
\end{document}
```