# Display count of leaves(depth) at each level in tree

Tags: forest, trees

I am drawing a tree like given below. The MWE for it is below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}   
\usepackage{forest}   
\title{}   
\author{}   
\begin{document}   
\date{}   
\begin{forest}   
    [n   
    [n-1   
    [n-2[$\vdots$]][n-2[$\vdots$]]]   
    [n-1   
    [n-2[$\vdots$]][n-2[$\vdots$]]]]   
\end{forest}   
\end{document}
```

[image: tree]

I wish to write the count of number of nodes at each level of the tree.
For example, adjacent to *n*, I wish to write 1. In the next level, 2 and so on.
Since I am using `forest` package,

```
[n\hspace{1cm}1]
```

doesn't seem to help. Any simple ideas on how to do this?

#### Edit 1:

I found [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302864/depth-labels-in-recursion-tree-using-forest?rq=1) which is not working for me.

Comment: I'm not surprised you couldn't get the code to work. I've more-or-less abandoned `justtrees` as a bad job. Some of the design decisions just made it horrible. On the positive side, it taught me to avoid those 'easy' solutions when writing `prooftrees`, though I realise that's not much consolation to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Forest` already counts levels, so a separate function to do this is superfluous. In addition, minimising the use of `pgfmath` will speed compilation. (Not an issue if this is your only tree and it is this simple, but more of a problem if you have many or complex trees.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree=math content,
  before drawing tree={
    tikz+={\coordinate (a) at (current bounding box.east);},
    for nodewalk={fake=r, L, ancestors}{
      if={>O+t_+t={content}{\vdots}}{
        tikz+={\node [anchor=base west] at (.base -| a) {$2^k$};}
      }{%
        tikz+/.process={Ow+Pw}{level}{int(2^#1)}{\node [anchor=base west] at (.base -| a) {#1};}
      }
    }
  }
  [n   
    [n-1   
      [n-2
        [\vdots]
      ]
      [n-2
        [\vdots]
      ]
    ]   
    [n-1   
      [n-2
        [\vdots]
      ]
      [n-2
        [\vdots]
      ]
    ]
  ]   
\end{forest}   

\end{document}
```

[image: tree with labelled levels]

Comment: Yes, forest counts levels, this is neat!

Comment: @GermanShepherd Indeed, isn't Forest neat? So surprising how much you can pull out for free :).

Comment: @cfr Hello, Could you help me to draw a recursion tree for ``T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/4)+n^2`` using justtrees package that you provided it? Thank you.

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302864/depth-labels-in-recursion-tree-using-forest?noredirect=1&lq=1 I read this post.

Comment: @MR_ I'd recommend asking a new question. `justtrees` turned out to be problematic and I dropped it, so it may or may not work with current Forest. But you can do the same directly with Forest if necessary.

Comment: @cfr I asked here, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702119/draw-recursion-tree , could you see that?

Answer (score 2):

A simple robust way would be to name one of the nodes in each level and use the y coordinate of that node (making use of the `calc` tikzlibrary) to get the correct height for each label. Counting the number of nodes can be done progrmatically - in your case the formula is clearly `2^n` (use pgfs `pow`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % let
\newcommand\leftsep{3} % How far left of center line of forest labels appear (cm)
\newcounter{levelcount} % Stores current level in tree
\newcommand\countnodes[1]{% Command to add label at height of node #1
    \draw let \p{L} = (#1) in (-\leftsep,\y{L}) node {\pgfmathparse{int(pow(2,\value{levelcount}))}\pgfmathresult};
    \stepcounter{levelcount} % Step counter for next level
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[n, name=root % Name root
[n-1, name=level1 % Name a node in level 1
[n-2, name=level2 [$\vdots$]][n-2[$\vdots$]]] % Name a node in level 2
[n-1
[n-2[$\vdots$]][n-2[$\vdots$]]]]
{% Node counting - these must be in order
\countnodes{root}
\countnodes{level1}
\countnodes{level2}
}
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: After the vdots, I would like to write 2 raised to k, for the k-th level of nodes. I assume this cannot be done using this approach.

Comment: Sure, just name your `vdots` node e.g. `mydots` and add a command like `\draw let \p{L} = (mydots) in (-\leftsep,\y{L}) node {$2^k$};` in the same group (`{..}`) as the `\countnodes` commands.  (If you want it below the vdots, use e.g. `\y{L}-1` instead of `\y{L}`.)