# Special characters in parsetree

Tags: trees

I am using the [parsetree](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2003s/ctl230/LaTeX/parsetree.sty) package, which according to [this documentation](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/trees/parsetree/#5) can have special characters like parentheses in leaf nodes when not using shortcuts like ".N.". However even if I follow these rules, I still cannot get my special characters to be shown.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parsetree}
\begin{document}

\begin{parsetree}
\ptbegtree
\ptbeg{}\ptnode{ROOT}
 \ptbeg{}\ptleaf{((parentheses))}
  \ptend\ptend{}
  \ptendtree
\end{parsetree}
\end{document}
```

Instead of "((parentheses))", just "parentheses" is shown.

Comment: I get ‘You don't have permission to view “parsetree.sty”’

Comment: I provided an alternative link.

Comment: Please change the tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples in the documentation work fine, but your example is wrong. If you wish to use special characters within the tree, you need to use the low-level commands ***instead of*** the `parsetree` environment - not in addition to it.

Here's what the documentation says:

> The `parsetree` environment is simply a wrapper that: (a) makes these special characters 'active' (i.e. special), and (b) calls the commands `\ptbegtree` `\ptendtree` at the beginning and end of the environment respectively. If we use these latter commands directly, then these special characters retain their normal meanings, and can appear in node lables [*sic.*]. However, we must now use the underlying `parsetree` commands to draw the tree ...

The point is that, within the `parsetree` environment, the category codes are changed. So the special characters are short-hands for the lower-level commands.

If you need to use those characters in the nodes of the tree, then you need the category codes to be their usual selves.

One solution would be to create a mechanism to temporarily change the codes back. However, that is not the solution supported by the package.

What the package supports instead is direct use of the lower-level commands, so that the category codes remain their usual selves. Obviously, this means you cannot use the special characters as short-hands. But you can use them within the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parsetree}
\begin{document}
\ptbegtree
  \ptbeg\ptnode{ROOT}
    \ptbeg\ptleaf{((parentheses))}
    \ptend
  \ptend
\ptendtree
\ptbegtree
  \ptbeg \ptnode{(VP)}
      \ptbeg \ptnode{(V)}    \ptleaf{(`saw)}  \ptend
      \ptbeg \ptnode{NP}     \ptleaf{Sam's~~~toy.} \ptend
   \ptend
\ptendtree
\end{document}
```

[image: working examples]

## Alternative Solutions

A modern package such as **forest** or **qtree** or **tikz-qtree** would definitely make life easier.

Here are four examples from above and/or the documentation for **parsetree** redone using **forest**. This makes it possible to use common styling and to specify the trees very concisely using bracket notation.

For a brief introduction to **forest** and an explanation of the brackets syntax, see the [second part of my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254926/) to an earlier question.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
```

Load **array** as we want it for trees whose nodes are multiline maths.

Define two standard styles: `my forest` for primarily-text-in-nodes trees and `my maths forest` for primarily-maths-in-nodes trees. You can always switch within a node, of course, but this saves repeating the same switches for every node as a routine.

```
\forestset{
  my forest/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
```

Branches start from a common point below the parent and end top centre of the child.

```
      align=center
```

Align node contents centrally.

```
    }
  },
  my maths forest/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align={@{}>{$}c<{$}@{}}
```

As before, but the content of the nodes is in maths mode by default.

```
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
```

From the question:

```
\begin{forest}
  my forest
  [ROOT
    [\itshape(parentheses)]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: example 1]

Here's an example with a triangular roof:

```
\begin{forest}
  my forest,
  where n children=0{font=\itshape}{}
```

All terminal nodes should be italicised.

```
  [S
    [NP
      [we]
    ]
    [VP
      [V
        [gave]
      ]
      [NP
        [them]
      ]
      [NP
        [a toy, triangle]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: example 2]

The example involving the special characters:

```
\begin{forest}
  my forest
  [(VP)
    [(V)
      [\textit{(`saw)}]
    ]
    [NP
      [\textit{Sam's toy.}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: example 3]

The more complex example involving special characters from the documentation:

```
\begin{forest}
  my maths forest
  [{S\\see' (s, k)\\\lambda y see' ( y,k ) (s)}
    [NP\\s
      [Sam\\s
      ]
    ]
    [{VP\\\lambda y see' ( y,k )\\\lambda x \lambda y see' ( y,x ) (k)}
      [{V\\\lambda x \lambda y see' ( y,x ) }
        [{saw\\\lambda x \lambda y see ( y,x )}
        ]
      ]
      [NP\\k
        [Kim\\k
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: example 4]

```
\end{document}
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
\forestset{
  my forest/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center
    }
  },
  my maths forest/.style={
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align={@{}>{$}c<{$}@{}}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  my forest
  [ROOT
    [\itshape(parentheses)]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  my forest,
  where n children=0{font=\itshape}{}
  [S
    [NP
      [we]
    ]
    [VP
      [V
        [gave]
      ]
      [NP
        [them]
      ]
      [NP
        [a toy, triangle]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
  my forest
  [(VP)
    [(V)
      [\textit{(`saw)}]
    ]
    [NP
      [\textit{Sam's toy.}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  my maths forest
  [{S\\see' (s, k)\\\lambda y see' ( y,k ) (s)}
    [NP\\s
      [Sam\\s
      ]
    ]
    [{VP\\\lambda y see' ( y,k )\\\lambda x \lambda y see' ( y,x ) (k)}
      [{V\\\lambda x \lambda y see' ( y,x ) }
        [{saw\\\lambda x \lambda y see ( y,x )}
        ]
      ]
      [NP\\k
        [Kim\\k
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You quoted the documentation: the more I read it, the less I understand.

Comment: Well, I think I understand it. But I'm assuming I must be mistaken if you don't understand it. I thought it was pretty simple: `parsetree` does 2 things. One of those is switching the cat codes. If you don't use `parsetree` but just do the second non-cat-code-changing thing, then the cat codes stay what they usually are and you can use the special characters normally in nodes. (`\newenvironment{parsetree}{\ptactivechardefs\ptbegtree}{\ptendtree}`)

Comment: Fantastic! I wish I could upvote it again.

Comment: It's the thought that counts ;). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason whatsoever that can make the advertised examples work, if you use the `parsetree` environment. Indeed, they don't, because the `\ptnode` and `\ptleaf` macros don't change the category codes of the special characters back before absorbing their arguments.

According to cfr, the `parsetree` environment shouldn't be used when the `\ptnode` and `\ptleaf` commands are used. However, we can use the best of both worlds by just juggling category codes around. Here's how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parsetree}

% Fix the wrong macros of parsetree.sty
\def\ptnodeaux#1{\setbox\ptx=\hbox\bgroup\ptuncatcodes\ptnodeauxaux{#1}}
\def\ptnodeauxaux#1#2{#1#2\egroup\ptxx=0.5\wd\ptx\ptnext}
\def\ptnode{\ptnodeaux{\ptnodefn\ptnodestrut}}
\def\ptleaf{\ptnodeaux{\ptleaffn\ptleafstrut}}
\def\ptuncatcodes{%
  \catcode`(=12 \catcode`)=12
  \catcode`.=12 \catcode``=12
  \def~{\nobreakspace{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{parsetree}
\ptbeg\ptnode{ROOT}
 \ptbeg\ptleaf{(parentheses)}
  \ptend\ptend
\end{parsetree}

\begin{parsetree}
\ptbeg \ptnode{(VP)}
  \ptbeg \ptnode{(V)}    \ptleaf{(`saw)}  \ptend
  \ptbeg \ptnode{NP}     \ptleaf{Sam's~~~toy.} \ptend
  \ptend
\end{parsetree}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't there be a space between "Sam's" and "toy"?  (and maybe it's from looking too long at math, but i find those italic parentheses jarring.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, yes, I uncatcoded too much!

Comment: @cfr The documentation was really unclear. I don't think this warrants a downvote and I'm going to remove this answer as soon as the OP reverts the tick. In LaTeX one *expects* to have `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`, so I thought, like the OP, that the examples simply assumed them.

Comment: @cfr Is it good now? Why don't you give some examples with `forest` or the other packages you're expert in?

Comment: @egreg Yes, thank you. (I changed my vote accordingly.)

Comment: Should the contents be maths or text?

Comment: @cfr Some examples like the ones here or in the documentation of `parsetree`.

Comment: @egreg Will that do?