# How to install forest package with MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, forest

I am using Latex trough TeXnicCenter with core of MikTeX...in this week news I've found something about tree graphs and I wanted to try it by myself but when I used appropriate code (copied from the code on the page) MikTeX tried to install forest package automatically but it got stucked with error: 
pdflatex> ! LaTex Error: File 'elocalloc.sty' not found 
...I've read "Not so short introduction to Latex2" but I am no expert... maybe it would be enough to instal this one manually but I am not sure where to download it and how to do it...

Comment: synchronize the package database. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/2388

Comment: I did it, but now it has different problems (38 errors), but maybe it wasn't done properly :/

Comment: You need to update your installation of TeX generally. You have an outdated LaTeX base which is responsible for that error. The number of errors you get is pretty much completely useless information. What is the first one? Please also post the exact minimal document you are trying to compile. Telling us it is the code you copied from some unknown page of something unknown is really not helpful.

Comment: I used code from here (first answer) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295330/write-trees-in-latex?newsletter=1&nlcode=558565%7ce18f 
And first error: pdflatex> ! Package xparse error: support package 13kernel  too old \\

So maybe you are right and I have old version of Tex in general... so you suggest to upload MikTeX? Because it would want to do some critical updates (according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490 ) and I cannot risk that MikTeX stop working... I am using it for writing master thesis :(

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Launch `MiKTeX Package Manager`, wait until it displays the list of packages, select `forest` , right-click on it and choose `install`. The error message says you need to install `elocalloc`:

[image]

Comment: Thx, I tried, but it was showing that it is already instaled, even though it does not work. I tried to uninstal it and than instal it again... but after while of working it showed no progress for a long time so I closed the instalation window...Then I tried it again but it showed basicaly the same errors.

Comment: Also install the  `elocalloc` package, as the error message says.