# Use tikz to draw a hierarchical model (mult-level model from statistics)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

I am trying to draw a representation of a statistical multi-level model: examples of what I am trying to do can be seen in figures 3a or 3b, at http://www.esourceresearch.org/tabid/332/Default.aspx.

[image]

I have made an attempt, but cannot get the spacing correct. In the figure below, the children of `c1` and `cn` overlap (so that only the child of `cn` can be seen). I also do not know how to appropriately add the dots between each of the levels: between `one` and `two` and `two` and `n`, and between `t1` and `tn`, and so on. I tried just adding an extra child node, but I from the looks of it, it is not the way to go. Thanks.

[image]

My code

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[landscape, left=10pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}

% styles
\tikzstyle{every node} = [rectangle, draw,  text centered, rounded corners, fill=blue!20, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=1cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=1.25cm]

\node { one } 
  child { node {c1}
    child { node {t1}}
    child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
    child { node {tn}}
  }
  child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}
  }
  child { node {cn}
    child { node {t1}}
    child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
    child { node {tn}}
  }
  ;

\hspace*{7cm} \node { two }
  child { node {c1}
    child { node {t1}}
    child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
    child { node {tn}}
  }
  child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}
  }
  child { node {cn}
    child { node {t1}}
    child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
    child { node {tn}}
   };

\hspace*{7cm} \node { n }
  child { node {c1}
    child { node {t1}}
    child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
    child { node {tn}}
  }
  child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}
  }
  child { node {cn}
    child { node {t1}}
    child { node [draw=none] {\ldots}}
    child { node {tn}}
   };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I recommend the specialist tree-drawing package, Forest?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  delay={
    where content={}{
      if level=0{}{
        content=\ldots,
        math content,
        no edge,
        fit=band,
      },
    }{
      rounded corners,
      outer color=blue!20,
      inner color=blue!15,
      minimum height=1cm,
      minimum width=1cm,
      draw,
      drop shadow,
    },
  }
  [, phantom
    [one, plain content
      [c_1
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
    ]
    [two, plain content
      [c_1
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
    ]
    []
    [n
      [c_1
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: Forest tree]

## EDIT

Here's a fancier version which defines `label levels` as a style for trees which should have level labels. Labels should be added within the tree using `level label=<label text>` and will be concatenated to form a label for that level, preceded by the prefix `Label <level number>`. All of this can be adjusted, of course.

I've also added a fancier background, but that's obviously strictly optional.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fit,backgrounds}
\forestset{
  declare toks={level label}{},
  declare toks register={level labels},
  level labels={},
  declare count register={leveller},
  leveller'=0,
  level split/.style={
    temptoksa={#1},
    split register={temptoksa}{:}{tempcounta,level label split},
  },
  level label split/.style={
    temptoksb={#1},
    temptoksc={},
    split register={temptoksb}{,}{temptoksc, level label splitter},
    tikz+/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={
      \node (label leveller ##1) [anchor=east, align=right, font=\sffamily] at (level ##1.west -| westpoint) {##2};
    }{tempcounta}{temptoksc},
    before computing xy/.wrap pgfmath arg={
      tikz+={
        \node [anchor=north east, align=right, font=\sffamily\itshape] at (label leveller ##1.north -| west of westpoint) {Level ##1};
      },
    }{tempcounta},
  },
  level label splitter/.style={
    temptoksc+={\\#1},
  },
  label levels/.style={
    tikz+={
      \coordinate (westpoint) at ([xshift=-15pt]current bounding box.west);
    },
    before packing={
        tikz+={
        \coordinate (west of westpoint) at ([xshift=-15pt]current bounding box.west);
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={
      tikz+={
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [left color=blue!50!cyan!25!white, right color=blue!50!cyan!25!white, middle color=blue!50!cyan, inner sep=10pt, rounded corners, draw=blue!50!cyan, draw opacity=.5, fill opacity=.15, fit=(current bounding box)] {};}
      },
    },
    delay={
      for tree breadth-first={
        if level label={}{}{
          if={(level())>(leveller)}{
            leveller/.option=level,
            alias/.wrap pgfmath arg={level ##1}{level()},
            if level labels={}{}{
              level labels+={;},
            },
            level labels+/.option=level,
            level labels+={:},
          }{},
          level labels+/.option=level label,
          level labels+={,},
        },
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if level labels={}{}{
        split register={level labels}{;}{level split},
      },
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  delay={
    where content={}{
      if level=0{}{
        content=\ldots,
        math content,
        no edge,
        fit=band,
      },
    }{
      rounded corners,
      outer color=blue!20,
      inner color=blue!15,
      minimum height=1cm,
      minimum width=1cm,
      draw,
      drop shadow,
    },
  },
  label levels,
  [, phantom
    [one, plain content, level label=platitudes
      [c_1
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
    ]
    [two, plain content
      [c_1
        [t_1, level label=latitudes]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n, level label=longitudes]
      ]
    ]
    []
    [n
      [c_1, level label=magnitudes
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1]
        []
        [t_n]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: fancier with labelled levels]

Comment: If you want the level labels at the left, let me know. `justtrees` can do this straightforwardly and I need stuff to test it on. Or I can just show you how to do it a little less straightforwardly without `justtrees` ;).

Comment: that looks great, thank you. I had actually noticed a few of your previous posts using`forest` but hadn't managed to produce anything reasonable. If there is a way to adapt this to add labels on the left that would be great, but as is im very happy.

Comment: @user20650 Please see edit above. Forest takes some getting used to, but it is really nice and well worth the effort.

Comment: That looks really great. Thank you so much. As I mentioned above, I had seen your previous forest answers, but I had found the syntax a little to grasp. But im convinced, to make an effort. Is the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest guide best place to start?

Comment: @user20650 Yes. For a simple introduction to the syntax, you might try this answer of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex/254926#254926. The question is not about Forest, so it doesn't have the `forest` tag, but I try to give a very basic intro to Forest in the answer.

Comment: @cfr If you want, I'm sure you can improve this [`poor man` code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333886/1952)

Comment: @Ignasi Not sure whether [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333904/) constitutes an improvement, exactly. It is certainly more complicated. ;)