# How to draw hierarchical overlapping models

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs, trees

I am trying to draw hierarchical models with overlapping nodes. I am able to use [Use tikz to draw a hierarchical model (mult-level model from statistics)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333672/use-tikz-to-draw-a-hierarchical-model-mult-level-model-from-statistics) to make hierarchical models, but I am not able to figure out how to draw overlapping nodes and also how to add weights to the edges. I want to draw the structure given in the following figure [image: z]

Comment: It is always a good idea to show us what you have been able to do. Apart from making it easier to answer the question, you are more likely to get a solution that is taylor-made for your situation and uses your conventions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard trick is to add the non-tree stuff via Ti*k*Z. The basis of all this is [cfr's answer you link to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333672/use-tikz-to-draw-a-hierarchical-model-mult-level-model-from-statistics).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fit,backgrounds}
\forestset{
  declare toks={level label}{},
  declare toks register={level labels},
  level labels={},
  declare count register={leveller},
  leveller'=0,
  level split/.style={
    temptoksa={#1},
    split register={temptoksa}{:}{tempcounta,level label split},
  },
  level label split/.style={
    temptoksb={#1},
    temptoksc={},
    split register={temptoksb}{,}{temptoksc, level label splitter},
    tikz+/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={
      \node (label leveller ##1) [anchor=east, align=right, font=\sffamily] at (level ##1.west -| westpoint) {##2};
    }{tempcounta}{temptoksc},
    before computing xy/.wrap pgfmath arg={
      tikz+={
        \node [anchor=north east, align=right, font=\sffamily\itshape] at (label leveller ##1.north -| west of westpoint) {Level ##1};
      },
    }{tempcounta},
  },
  level label splitter/.style={
    temptoksc+={\\#1},
  },
  label levels/.style={
    tikz+={
      \coordinate (westpoint) at ([xshift=-15pt]current bounding box.west);
    },
    before packing={
        tikz+={
        \coordinate (west of westpoint) at ([xshift=-15pt]current bounding box.west);
      },
    },
    before drawing tree={
      tikz+={
        \scoped[on background layer]{\node [left color=blue!50!cyan!25!white, right color=blue!50!cyan!25!white, middle color=blue!50!cyan, inner sep=10pt, rounded corners, draw=blue!50!cyan, draw opacity=.5, fill opacity=.15, fit=(current bounding box)] {};}
      },
    },
    delay={
      for tree breadth-first={
        if level label={}{}{
          if={(level())>(leveller)}{
            leveller/.option=level,
            alias/.wrap pgfmath arg={level ##1}{level()},
            if level labels={}{}{
              level labels+={;},
            },
            level labels+/.option=level,
            level labels+={:},
          }{},
          level labels+/.option=level label,
          level labels+={,},
        },
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if level labels={}{}{
        split register={level labels}{;}{level split},
      },
    },
  }
}
\tikzset{cute fancy rodent/.style={rounded corners,
      outer color=blue!20,
      inner color=blue!15,
      minimum height=1cm,
      minimum width=1cm,
      draw,
      drop shadow}}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  delay={
    where content={}{
      if level=0{}{
        content=\ldots,
        math content,
        no edge,
        fit=band,
      },
    }{
      cute fancy rodent
    },
  },
  label levels,
  [, phantom
    [one, plain content, level label=platitudes
      [c_1
        [t_1,alias=t1a]
        []
        [t_n,alias=tna]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1,alias=t1b]
        []
        [t_n,alias=tnb]
      ]
    ]
    [two, plain content
      [c_1
        [t_1, level label=latitudes,alias=t1c]
        []
        [t_n,alias=tnc]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1,alias=t1d]
        []
        [t_n, level label=longitudes,alias=tnd]
      ]
    ]
    []
    [n
      [c_1, level label=magnitudes
        [t_1,alias=t1e]
        []
        [t_n,alias=tne]
      ]
      []
      [c_n
        [t_1,alias=t1f]
        []
        [t_n,alias=tnf]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\foreach \X in {a,...,f}  
{\path (t1\X) -- (tn\X) node[midway,below=2.5em,cute fancy rodent] 
(tm\X){$m_x$};
\draw (t1\X) -- (tm\X) (tm\X) -- (tn\X);
}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]