# LaTeX beamer create Tries and PATRICIA Trees

Tags: beamer, trees, draw, qtree

Already checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5451) post to see how to draw a simple tree in LaTeX, however, I would like to generate Tries with LaTeX and since those kind of trees have the keys on their edges instead of in the nodes, I wasn't able to find a quick solution for this.
And would it also be possible to show each step of an action (search, insert, delete) on a different slide?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide us some more information on how the trees you want to create are supposed to look like. Please note that not everybody is an expert in the specific field you are dealing with. Furthermore, is there anything you have already tried? In this case, please share your source code. In general, you may want to have a look at TikZ, which offers almost everything for creating trees you can imagine. There are a lot of useful examples in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Is this the kind of tree you're trying to create? If so your question is a duplicate, I think. [Creating Trie trees in TikZ](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/182460).  On animating `forest` trees in Beamer, see [Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/109950).