# How to draw this tree diagram?

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw this tree diagram in LaTex? 
[image]

Comment: Try looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex) to get started. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: It can be done using TikZ something like this:http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tree/ . You need to try to do it, and then ask if you have any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This is to give you a *start*. I am convinced that you *could* also add the `H` and `T` programmatically, but I do not have motivation now to spell this out (the more so since I am not sure if that's what you want).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0cm,l sep=1.2cm,font=\sffamily,
where n children=0{rotate=90,anchor=west,edge={thick,-{Latex}}}{},
edge={thick}
}
  [H,alias=L1
   [H,alias=L2
    [H,alias=L3
     [H,alias=L4
      [H,alias=L5
       [HHHHH,alias=L6]
      ]
      [T
       [HHHHT]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HHHTH]
      ]
      [T
       [HHHTT]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [T
     [H
      [H
       [HHTHH]
      ]
      [T
       [HHTHT]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HHTTH]
      ]
      [T
       [HHTTT]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [T
    [H
     [H
      [H
       [HTHHH]
      ]
      [T
       [HTHHT]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HTHTH]
      ]
      [T
       [HTHTT]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [T
     [H
      [H
       [HTTHH]
      ]
      [T
       [HTTHT]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HTTTH]
      ]
      [T
       [HTTTT]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {First,Second,Third,Fourth,Fifth} 
{\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (L6.north|-L\Y){\X\ flip};} 
\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (L6.north){Outcome}; 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*NOTE**: Almost everything I know about forest I learned from some answers by cfr, who really is a forest master. If you consider upvoting this, please upvote some answer(s) by her instead. That way you will certainly cast a deserved upvote.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,width=0.5\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0cm,l sep=1.2cm,font=\sffamily,
where n children=1{rotate=90,anchor=west,edge={thick,-{Latex}}}{},
edge={thick}
}
  [H,alias=L1
   [H,alias=L2
    [H,alias=L3
     [H,alias=L4
      [H,alias=L5
       [HHHHH,alias=L6
        [$5$,alias=L7]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HHHHT
        [$3$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HHHTH
       [$3$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HHHTT
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [T
     [H
      [H
       [HHTHH
        [$3$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HHTHT
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HHTTH
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HHTTT
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [T
    [H
     [H
      [H
       [HTHHH
        [$3$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HTHHT
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HTHTH
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HTHTT
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [T
     [H
      [H
       [HTTHH
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HTTHT
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [HTTTH
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [HTTTT
        [$-3$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {First,Second,Third,Fourth,Fifth} 
{\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (L6.north|-L\Y){\X\ flip};} 
\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (L6.north){Outcome}; 
\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (L7.west){Lands on}; 
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,width=0.47\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
for tree={s sep=0cm,l sep=1.2cm,font=\sffamily,
where n children=1{rotate=90,anchor=west,edge={thick,-{Latex}}}{},
edge={thick}
}
  [T,alias=L1
   [H,alias=L2
    [H,alias=L3
     [H,alias=L4
      [H,alias=L5
       [THHHH,alias=L6
        [$3$,alias=L7]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [THHHT
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [THHTH
       [$1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [THHTT
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [T
     [H
      [H
       [THTHH
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [THTHT
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [THTTH
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [THTTT
        [$-3$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [T
    [H
     [H
      [H
       [TTHHH
        [$1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [TTHHT
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [TTHTH
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [TTHTT
        [$-3$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    [T
     [H
      [H
       [TTTHH
        [$-1$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [TTTHT
        [$-3$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
     [T
      [H
       [TTTTH
        [$-3$]
       ]
      ]
      [T
       [TTTTT
        [$-5$]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KJO You are right, thanks! I just removed it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's really helpful! Can I ask you one more question? How can I produce one more line:Lands on: 5 3 3 1 3 1 1 -1 3 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -3?
And Is that possible to put graph for H and graph for T side by side?