# How to draw picture like this in Latex?

Tags: diagrams, trees

How can I draw picture like this in Latex?

Any pointers welcome.

[image]

Comment: See `forest` package. Its documentation contain examples with similar trees.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I draw simple trees in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5447/5764)

Comment: @downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: @Exploring To explain the downvoting: we generally prefer that questioners have tried to solve their problems and not just turn to TeX.SE as a coding service.  If you need a starting point, most web searches would be able to do that.  If you've already made a start and gotten stuck, then it would be best if you showed us what you have so far, and what part you're stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with the `tikz` package using `tikzstyle` to define how you want things to look.

Add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm,
 minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=red, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
```

The third line defines the shape of our blocks. The fourth line defines the shape of our arrows.

To draw a diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (start) [block] {Start};
\node (stop) [block, below of=start] {Stop};
\node (other) [block, right of=stop, xshift=2cm] {Other};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (stop);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (other);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

A `node` works like this:

`\node (label) [style] {Text};`

The label gives you a way to refer to it, such as when you are drawing arrows. The style comes from the `tikzstyle` that you defined in your preamble, and the Text is the actual text you want to appear in your box. (Don't forget the closing semicolon.)

This will give you:

[image: Simple trees diagram]

**Edit:** There are other examples [here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/).