# Align elements with each other in forest environment

Tags: forest

I'm working with phrase structure trees in linguistics, and I've just created the following tree

[image]

Which has the following source code:

```tex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    [PP 
    [P\\in]
    [NP [D\\the] [N\\hat]]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to have the words "in," "the," and "hat" vertically aligned with each other. I've been reading through the documentation of forest, and I've seen how vertical displacement could be specified, but I would like for these nodes to be *anchored* to each other, if that makes sense, so that if I make any modifications to this tree, no matter what, all three of those will still be on the same vertical plane.

Are there any options with the `forest` package to do this?

Comment: `where n children=0{tier=word}{}` at the top of page 7 of the manual.

Comment: Examples of a bit complex trees you can find in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687344/